# Weird resizing in every browser except IE

Tags: css, xhtml, cross-browser

I've been coding my site and it looks perfect in IE 8 but when I view it in Safafi, Chrome, and Firefox. Everything is unexplicably smaller. **How do I make the webpage look normal like it does in the IE 8 browser?**

My site is at : http://www.jjosephs.byethost22.com/visibility/fixed/index_2.htm

I've been messing with he code for days now trying to get it to work in all 4 browsers. I've pasted the css code below, maybe something will jump out at you css gurus.

```
/* Eric Myers - CSS Reset v1.0 | 20080212 */

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
}
body {

    background-color: rgb(85,105,94);
    font-family:"Gill Sans MT", "Gill Sans", sans-serif;
    color:white;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}

/* remember to define focus styles! */
:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

/* remember to highlight inserts somehow! */
ins {
    text-decoration: none;
}
del {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

/* tables still need 'cellspacing="0"' in the markup */
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

/*
      Created by Keith Donegan of Code-Sucks.com

      E-Mail: Keithdonegan@gmail.com

      You can do whatever you want with these layouts,
      but it would be greatly appreciated if you gave a link
      back to http://www.code-sucks.com

*/

* { padding: 0; margin: 0; }

#wrapper { 
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 922px;
}

#leftcolumn {
 margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
 padding: 10px;
 height: 500px;
 width: 155px;
 float: left;
}
#content { 
 float: left;
 margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
 padding: 10px;
 height: 500px;
 width: 490px;
 display: inline;
 line-height:110%;
 font-family:"Gill Sans MT", "Gill Sans", sans-serif;
}
#rightcolumn { 
 margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
 padding: 10px;
 height: 500px;
 width: 155px;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
}


#background_gradient img{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
}

#background_logo img{
    position:absolute;
    left:-271px;
    top:-134px;
    z-index:-1;
    display:inline;
}

#coming_soon_img{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}

#logo_large{
    float:right;
}

#landing_text{
    clear:both;
}

#first_paragraph, #company_name, #street_address, .contact_short, #copyright{
    color:#ffffff;
}

#landing_text{
    font-size:15px;
    line-height:20px;
}

.colored_text{
    color:#bd9e00;
}

#first_paragraph{
    font-size:20.5px;
    font-weight:bold;
}

#first_paragraph span{
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:italic;
}

#lower_half{
    margin-top:26px;
}

#tag_line{
    font-size:17px;
    float:left;
}


#call_to_action_button{
    float:right;
}

#company_name{
    font-size:13.5px;
}

#horizontal_line{
    margin-top:15px;
}

#footer_text{
    font-size:7.5px;
    font-family:arial, "Gill Sans MT", sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
}

#logo_micro, #address_details{
    float:left;
}

#address_details{
    margin-left:12.5px;
}

#contact_details{
    display:block;
    line-height:80%;
}

.specific_contact_details, .specific_contact_details a{
    color:#bd9e00;
}

#copyright{
    float:right;
    font-size:6.5px;
}
.other_landing_text{
    line-height:121.5%;
    color:#313031;
}
```

Comment: I'm sure others will chime in, but as a side note, using `px` for font sizes isn't recommended.

Comment: You're worrying too much. You control the basic layout and style, not the exact fonts or sizes. That said, I don't see the difference in FF and IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure it isn't something like you are zoomed in on IE8 because `font-size:7.5px;` is supposed to be really small.

Comment: Yeah, I was zoomed in on IE :-/. It's the same fine print across all 3 browsers so I got cross-browser compatability at least. Going to increase everything by a certain ratio to see if I can a page which doesn't blind my users.

Answer (score 0):

Looks great in IE7, Chrome, Safari, FF, except the transparent .png images don't work in IE6.  Nice job!